# systemd-machined not found in debian systemd package

Tags: debian, systemd, packages, containers

I have a docker container running a very bare version of debian stretch.  with this, I have to install systemd externally first. To do this, I have a docker container that runs the install, then I commit it to an image, I then run systemd from that image.  When I bash into the container, machinectl is not found anywhere on the file system and machined does not seem to be running.  Is there a specific package I need to install? Or due to the fact I am in a container to begin with, is machined not available?  I recognize that containers in containers are frowned upon, but this container's purpose is for running tests interfacing with systemd-machined.

Steps to reproduce:

```
docker run --privileged --cidfile=/tmp/cidfile debian:stretch bash -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential git dbus libsystemd-dev libpam-systemd'
docker commit `cat /tmp/cidfile` deb-machined-test
rm /tmp/cidfile
docker run -d --cidfile=/tmp/cidfile --privileged deb-machined-test /bin/systemd --system
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out systemd-machined is in a separate package from the main systemd package.  In order to install systemd-machined on Debian Stretch, you have to run `apt-get install -y systemd-container`.